# Full width CSS settings

Tags: css

Something is not right with my full width css on desktop. You can see in the screenshot link below how the container is not filling the left side.

I'm using:
width: 100vw;
position: relative;
left: 50%;
right: 50%;
margin-left: -50vw;
margin-right: -50vw;

[image: see screenshot]

The site is here https://livinghealthywithchocolate.com/recipes/ or you can see this happening in the homepage as well.

How do I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: `width: 100vw; position: relative; left: 50%; right: 50%; margin-left: -50vw; margin-right: -50vw;` is useless. but a reset on body margin could be usefull. A block container fills entire width avalaible. width:100% is not really needed, width:100vw will be a trouble once a scrollbar appears ....

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't happen in every screen size. You have a media query messing with the padding, if you remove the padding rule it works.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1023px)
.site-inner {
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    padding: 27px 37.5px;
}
```

Should be

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 1023px)
    .site-inner {
        margin: 20px auto 0;
    }
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I added the following and it fixed the problem :)  @media only screen and (min-width: 1023px) {
    .site-inner {
        padding: 0;
    }
}

Comment: Awesome! I just inspected the part where you were having trouble. Remember to use the browser dev tools (f12 in chrome) to debug this issues!

Answer (score -2):

You can add this to your CSS.

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}


Then set the width of the container to 100%.
```

Comment: are you aware that this will set the margins and paddings for *all* elements on that web page to zero? (including all browser default settings, line the top/bottom margins for headers and paragraphs)